# Windows 7 doesn't have any sound 

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, audio

I have Windows 7 newly installed on my PC (not pirated) but there is no sound.

I don't even know where to check whether it has been muted. Please advise.

[image]

---

The there is no triangle There are drivers and up-to-date now.

There are no icons that you listed above 
instead there is an icon with red cross mark with the speaker symbol

Answer (score 5):

Go to computer management (click on the Start Button/Orb, and right click on computer, then click manage).

Click on Device Manager and take a look to see if you have any yellow triangles. Yellow triangles basically mean either an error or driver/device not installed.

If you have a sound card, look at that companies website, or if it is built in to your motherboard, take a look at the motherboard manufacturers web page.

You need to basically find the sound driver which should be on their support / downloads page.

IF however you know the exact name of the sound driver, you may have luck going to the actual chip manufacturers website (e.g. [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw)) and searching, but you won't know unless you know what you have.

As for checking for mute - Look for the sound icon next to the clock and see if it has a cross through it. If you do not see the icon at all, it is probably an indication that there is a problem with sound on your system.

[image]

And, sorry, it has to be said - If you see no yellow triangle and the sound icon is there and unmuted, make sure your speakers are plugged in and working.

Comment: It is possible, especially if this is an older PC (that shipped with XP), that there are no manufacturer supported drivers for the chipset.  Sometimes its possible to install XP sound drivers on 7, however it doesnt always work.  If this is the case, you might have to disable sound in BIOS and buy a new sound card.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, what I did:

Install the original sound driver made for xp by the soundcard manufacturer!! It will run, if it cant run on win 7, then Win 7 would say some compatibility stuffs and make it compatible with win 7.

IF the above didnt work, go to sound card manufacturers website / search net to find drivers for ur sound driver compatible for win 7 then install, reboot ! Voila, sound is coming from speakers...!! I am sure it should work because it worked for me too!!!

Good luck!